# Enable 32-bit for debugging ASP.NET projects on VIsual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a 64-bit ASP.NET application which uses a 32-bit only library. If I am deploy this on IIS 7, I could enable 32-bit applications in the application pool. However, if I am debugging from Visual Studio 2010, how do I do simulate enabling 32-bit applications?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [IIS Express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx)? [Visual Studio 2010 SP1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/983509) supports it, as shown in [this blogpost](http://abhijitjana.net/2011/06/12/run-iis-express-and-cassini-simultaneously-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1/).